# Deserialize strange JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a deserialize a JSON string from a third party service and they provide it in this format:

```
[ [ "source", "sdi" ], [ "device", "dvi" ] ]
```

I have tried to create a data contract without the name but I can't seem to deserialize it. I've created a contract with a list that contains a list of strings but this json seems unordinary to me. Can this even be done given the expression above?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type `List<List<string>>` to deserialize....

```
string json = @"[ [ ""source"", ""sdi"" ], [ ""device"", ""dvi"" ] ]";
var listofLists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(json);
```

or

```
var listofLists = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(json);
```